# Asymptotic behavior of a function

Tags: real-analysis

Let $n\geq 2$, and define
$$\phi(t) = \int_{S^{n-1}} \cos(t \omega_1) d\omega,$$
where $S^{n-1}$ is the unit sphere in $n-$dimensional euclidean space, and $d\omega$ denote the surface area on $S^{n-1}$.

What can we say about the asymptotic behavior of $\phi(t)$ when $t$ tends to infinity? Does it know in literature?

Thanks

Comment: What is $\omega_1$? (In particular, what values does it take? When $n = 2$ is $\omega_1 \in [-1,1]$ or is it in $[0,2\pi)$?)

Comment: $\omega = (\omega_1,\cdots,\omega_n) \in S^{n-1}$.  Its value is in $[-1,1]$.

Comment: The marginal distribution of a coordinate on the sphere under uniform distribution is known to be related to the beta distribution, because it's the square root of the ratio  of two gamma distributed variables.

Answer (score 5):

$$\phi(t)=C_n\int_0^{\pi} \cos[t\cos\phi]\sin^{n-2}\phi\,d\phi$$

with $$C_n=\frac{2\pi^{n/2-1/2}}{\Gamma(n/2-1/2)}$$

this evaluates to

$$\phi(t)=\frac{2\pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma(n/2)}\,{}_0F_{1}(n/2;-t^2/4)$$

with $_0F_{1}$ the confluent hypergeometric function.

The large-$t$ asymptotics is

$$\phi(t)=2^{n/2+1/2}\pi^{n/2-1/2}t^{1/2-n/2}\sin(\pi/4+n\pi/4-t)[1+{\rm order}(1/t)].$$

Comment: ... and when $n$ is odd you don't even need hypergeometric functions (it is a simple integration by parts exercise). For $n = 3$ it is proportional to $\sin(t)/t$. For $n = 5$ to $\cos(t)/t + \sin(t)/t^2$ or something like that.

Comment: @Carlo Beenakker: Thanks for your suggestion. I try to compute formally this integral by using Taylors expansion of the function $\cos(t \omega_1)$ and compute the integral $\int \omega_1 ^{2k}$. Finally, I obtain one power serie which is exact the definition of confluent hypergeometric function. However, this serie is not good to find the asymptotic behavior. Could you introduce me a reference for this asymptotic behavior? Thanks again.